# iOS Split Table Views

Tags: ios, split, customization, tableview, instagram

1.) Im new to iOS development and now im creating a small app that have user profiles. This is much more similar to the "Instagram" app user profile. Its contain a image view with split row contents that are clickable. So how to create split table view cells ?

2.) And the other question is how add the segmented like control that loads different table view structure to the same view ?(Same way in Instagram app)

Please refer the attached image url please.

http://postimg.org/image/84u652rj5/

I have already deal with this situation but still i cant find a solution.
Can anyone give me a example/tutorial or any clue to get started.

Comment: What is your *first* question?

Comment: Hi H2CO3, I have Edit my question. Its how to split table view cell like Instagram app ?

Comment: That's a custom view. You can use the `imageView` property of the table view cell to display the image on the left, then add 3 `UILabels` and one `UIButton` at the appropriate positions.

Comment: Hi H2CO3, Thank you very much for the answer. Then the problem is in the 2nd part of the question. How to add the segmented like row and update only the bottom part of the table view with different contents in same table view without any changes/reload to the 1st part of the table view ?
Anyway thanks again for the 1st question.

Comment: You can reload specific cells only using the [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40).